# Remove the first and last parts of a URL string from AbsolutePath in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I'm not good with manipulating strings and could use a little help.

I'd have a URL (http://localhost/mySite/default.aspx) and I have the `AbsolutePath` as a string that I'm working with (/mySite/default.aspx):

```
string mySubUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

What I'm trying to do is remove the first and last parts of the `AbsolutePath`. In this example, removing "mySite" and "default.aspx", which would leave me with just "/".

There also may be instances where the URL is longer or shorter, e.g., http://localhost/mySite/mySubFolder/default.aspx, in which case after removing the first and last parts of the `AbsolutePath` I would be left with '/mySubFolder/'.

I did try working  a little with Uri segments but didn't get too far:

```
string absolutePath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
Uri uri = new Uri(absolutePath);
string[] pathSegments = uri.Segments;
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Will the beginning of the url *always* be `http://localhost/mySite`?

Comment: @DaveZych it would always be [http://localhost/](http://localhost/).

Comment: @dman2306 I added a little more information

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

```
string[] pathSegments = Request.Url.Segments.Skip(1).Take(Request.Url.Segments.Length - 2).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks. I tried this but `pathSegments` only returns "mySite/"

Answer (score 0):

The `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` already removes the left part of the Url for you, so it will give you something like `/subSection/subFolder/default.aspx`.

Then, you can remove the last part like this:

```
string absolutePath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
string[] urlSegments = absolutePath.Split('/');
urlSegments = urlSegments.Skip(1).Take(urlSegments.Length - 2);
string url = string.Join("/", urlSegments);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried implementing it but `url` is returning the full path "/mySite/subSection/subFolder/default.aspx".

Comment: thanks again. I did try the revised code but now I get only "mySite". Also, at the end of `urlSegments = urlSegments.Skip(1).Take(urlSegments.Length - 2)` should there be a `.ToArray()`?

Comment: That mean's your `AbsolutePath` is something else. You should be able to debug your code and see what's going on. No, `.ToArray()` is not required. `urlSegments` is already an array.

Comment: yes, urlSegments is an array, however Take() returns IEnumerable.